# Хранятся ли элементы в словаре как в списке

Tags: c#

Появилась надобность работать со словарём параллельно как со списком ключей/значений, ибо реализую что то вроде обхода графа в ширину, где рёбра имеют веса до определённой глубины (пока суммарный вес рёбер не достигнет какого то значения или не превысит его), использую обход в ширину, а не в глубину по той причине, что мне важен порядок вывода элементов после этого (нужно что бы выводилось "по слоям" начиная со стартовой вершины), от того и вопрос: если я делаю dictionary.Keys.ToList() (аналогично с Values) - сохраняется ли порядок элементов в таком списке по отношению к тому, в каком порядке в словарь добавлялись новые значения?(добавляются через dictionary[someKey] = someValue) Надеюсь достаточно понятно объяснил

Comment: Что вам мешает обратиться к учебным пособиям?

Comment: на вопрос вам ответили. было бы интересно взглянуть вообще на концепцию кода (наверно в отдельном вопросе с тегом инспекция-кода), т.к. я не уловил какая связь между обходом графа в ширину и словарём с фиксированным порядком.

Answer (score 3):

Уточните, какой именно тип вы используете в качестве dictionary? Вероятно, это `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. Он [реализован](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) как [Hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). В хэш-таблице порядок элементов в общем случае не гарантируется.

Для общего развития:
[Associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) имеет разные внутренние реализации: хэш-таблица, дерево поиска и другие.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [OrderedDictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=netcore-3.1) если важен порядок