# Замена текста в строке файла

Tags: c#, строки, файлы, foreach, replace

допустим есть некоторый файл ,этот файл считывается и записывается в массив , далее перебираем все строки ,и если есть нужная строка заменить ее на нужную , как избавиться от дублирования Replace вот код:

```
public const string oldPath = "/Logs" ;
public const string oldBatch = "/Packages/Batch";

public const string newPath = "/var/Logs";
public const string newBatch = "/Batch";

var currentSettings = new string[0];            
if (File.Exists(_configFile))
{
    OutputHelpers.WriteText("Current settings");
    currentSettings = File.ReadAllLines(_configFile);        
    foreach (string line in currentSettings)
    {                    
        string newline = line.Replace(oldPath, newPath).Replace(oldBatch,newBatch)
    }
```

Comment: Сделать коллекцию? Сделайте нечто, что будет хранить в себе старое и новое значение, можете Dictionary использовать и просто проходитесь по нему, меняя нужные значения.

Answer (score 0):

Пример работы в контексте отдельно взятой строки

```
const string oldPath = "/Logs";
const string oldBatch = "/Packages/Batch";

const string newPath = "/var/Logs";
const string newBatch = "/Batch";

String newline= "/Logs /var/Logs";
var pathDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(
StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
            {newPath, newBatch},
            {oldPath, oldBatch}
};
foreach (var item in pathDictionary)
{
            newline= newline.Replace(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Хочу заметить ошибку что сперва стоит обработать newPath, а затем oldPath...
В противном случае **"/Logs /var/Logs"** превратится в **"/Packages/Batch /var/Packages/Batch"**, а не в ожидаемое **"/Packages/Batch /Batch"**

Comment: Порядок элементов в Dictionary [не гарантируется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134656/184217).